# Trying to pass django-oscar products to custom template

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

I'm working on a custom template using a forked version of django-oscar apps (to have custom models).

I am trying to display a list of all the products in the product table, just to start with. I looked at django-oscar templates but as they rely on a lot of custom tempaltetags I found it too complex to rewrite everything to work with my models.

This is what I have in my views.py:

```
def product(request):
    template = loader.get_template('/home/mysite/django_sites/my_site/main_page/templates/main_page/product.html')
    prodlist = Product.objects.all()
    return HttpResponse(template.render({}, request), context={'prodlist': prodlist})
```

And the code I am using in my template to try and display it

```
{% for instance in prodlist%}
    <li>{{ instance.name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

However, this gives me an error

```
TypeError at /product/ 
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context'
```

/product corresponds to my product view in my urls.py

This was my best guess from following tutorials and looking at other answers. What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpResponse` doesn't have `context` arg.
Seems like you need to add context into `render`.

Try:

```
context={'prodlist': prodlist}
return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

Comment: Hmm, thank you! Although now I get ProgrammingError at /product/  ==newline==

column catalogue_product.collection_id does not exist  ==newline==

LINE 1: ..._updated", "catalogue_product"."is_discountable", "catalogue...

Comment: Did you run migrations? `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` ?

Comment: I did previously. I just ran makemigrations again now and it says no changed detected. Something to do with how I forked the app?-- ope, ran migrate and I am getting errors, will work on that!